# Local variables name collision

Tags: c++

If I define one variable in the enclosing block and another one with the same name in the nested block, how can I access a variable from the enclosing block inside the nested block?

```
int main ()
{
    int i = 0;
    {
        int i;
        i = 10;
    }
    cout << i; // prints 0
}
```

Comment: by giving it a better name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've ["shadowed"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the earlier definition, so it's basically gone. If you need access to it, pick a different name. As far as the compiler is concerned, within that inner block there's only one `i` and it has no idea about the other `i` that it replaced.

Either give it a better name:

```
int i = 0;
{
    int ii;
    i = 10;
}
cout << i; // prints 10
```

Or use a function:

```
int i = 0;
f(i);
cout << i; // Depends on what f() does.
```

Where you have:

```
void f(int& i) {
  i = 10;
}
```

Which *will* modify the original `i`.

Answer (score 1):

**If you can...**

Rename them:

```
int main ()
{
    int i = 0;
    {
        int j;
        i = 10;
    }
    cout << j; // prints 10
}
```

**If you cannot..**

No way. The `i` in the inner scope shadows the `i` from outer scope. You cannot access `i` from the outer scope after declaring a variable with the same name.